# How can I see system files in standard file dialog?

Tags: windows, winapi, opendialog

I can see hidden files, but cannot see superhidden.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Delphi setting or an `OpenDialog` setting. It's a Windows shell setting that the user can configure for herself, and you certainly shouldn't go messing with it.

If you want to change it on your *own* machine so that these files are visible, you can follow these steps:

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Open the Folder Options control panel.
3. Switch to the "View" tab.
4. Clear the check box labeled "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)".
5. Click OK.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks, but i'm don't need stupid way to do it.

Comment: I know in secret options of opendialog exist way to do it.

Comment: @user: Nope, there's no secret.

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent answer to this question at Raymond Chen's blog: [When people ask for security holes as features: Hiding files from Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/19/409620.aspx).

Comment: Raymond's article discusses a slightly different issue. It explains why there is no file attribute to make a file hidden irrespective of user preferences.